# dc.js color pie chart slice color with color domain

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I've got a pie chart with the following for coloring the slices.

```
.colorAccessor(function (d) {
        return d.value.count;
      })
 .colors(colorbrewer.YlGn[9])
 .colorDomain([0, grpXtents[1]])
```

I am calculating the grpXtents using `d3.extent`

This works fine. How do I recalculate the extents for my color domain when I click on filter on other charts in the group?

Thanks!

Comment: there is not enough info in the question. how are u creating elements currently? what other charts or filter are you referring to and how are they related?

Comment: I am getting elements from a ajax request. I have a custom reducer that gives me the d.value.count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not need to calculate it yourself. Please try this:

```
chart.on('preRedraw', function() {
    chart.calculateColorDomain();
});
```

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.colorMixin+calculateColorDomain

It should probably be an option on the colorMixin rather than requiring this hook.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. It works with the hook. Like you've mentioned it will really help if there was a simple switch enabling/ disabling recalculation of colorDomain on filters.